# Hibernate Collection Persistence

Tags: java, hibernate, collections, hibernate-mapping

While going through the Hibernate documentation I came across this statement which states that "Two entities cannot share a reference to the same collection instance", yet when I use the below code no error occurs.

Everything works fine including Hibernate persistence for both entities and corresponding collection references in the DB without any issue.

Am I misunderstanding something? Can this statement be explained and in which scenario is it applicable?

Entity 1:

```
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @CreationTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime date;

    @ElementCollection
    private List<String> phones = new ArrayList<>();

    @ElementCollection
    private Set<LocalDateTime> personOrderDates;
}
```

Entity 2:

```
public class Home {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    

    @ElementCollection
    private List<String> homePhoneList;
}
```

Hibernate persist code:

```
Person person1 = entityManager.find(Person.class, 48l);
Person person2 = entityManager.find(Person.class, 49l);
  
List<String> newPhoneList = new ArrayList();
newPhoneList.add("x");
newPhoneList.add("y");
newPhoneList.add("z");
    
person1.setPhones(newPhoneList);
person2.setPhones(newPhoneList);
Home home1 = Home.builder().homePhoneList(newPhoneList).build();
    
entityManager.persist(home1);
entityManager.persist(person1);
entityManager.persist(person2);
```

Here we clearly are able to share the same collection reference between two instances of the same entity (Person), as well as with entirely different entity type (Home) without any issue. All three entities are saving/updating in the DB.

Comment: And the sentence before that one reads: "The persistent collections injected by Hibernate behave like ArrayList, HashSet, TreeSet, HashMap or TreeMap, depending on the interface type". I don't think you're using "collections injected by Hibernate" here

Answer (score 0):

> Two entities cannot share a reference to the same collection instance

This is still correct. it means that if you load one of these entities and change phone collection, other entity's phone collection remains unchanged.

You are simply share a reference in your java and not in the database. Next time this shared reference will be gone and all of your entities consist of an individual reference to their own lists.